# How to add a widget to a pre-existing QLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlayout

I'm looking for a super simple example, and can't seem to find one. I have a `MainWindow`. When a button gets pressed, I want to create a new window that gets opened up in the layout of `MainWindow`, to become a part of it.

I have the code that sets up when a button is pushed to call this slot; when it gets called, my QLabel shows up, but my QWidget does not:

```cpp
QWidget *test = new QWidget();
test->setGeometry(QRect(100,100,100,100));
layout->addWidget(test,0,0)

//Operation Mode
QLabel *operationalModeLabel1 = new QLabel("TEST");
layout->addWidget(operationalModeLabel1,2,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for "lack of examples" is that you think of it wrong. What you describe is done all the time, by *every single Qt example that uses layouts*! I mean it. It *doesn't matter* when you add a widget to a layout. There's nothing magical about adding widgets "now" vs. adding them "later".

Just think of the title of the question: it makes *no sense*. All widgets must be added to layouts that already exist! *By definition*, no less. If there's no layout, how could you add a widget to it?

Your code is wrong, that's all. It's always pointless to set a geometry on a widget that is to be managed by a layout. As soon as you add it to the layout, the layout will change the  geometry.

Since you're adding an empty widget into the layout, you most likely won't be able to see it. That's why the label shows up - it's not an empty widget.

If you want a widget that has a fixed size, to make it easier to notice, just set the fixed size on it. Even better, make it red so that it stands out.

```
QWidget * test = new QWidget();
test->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: red }");
test->setFixedSize(100, 100);
layout->addWidget(test, 0, 0);
```

Comment: When you add a widget *does* matter in one important respect:  if you add a child QWidget to the layout of a parent-widget that is already visible, the new child QWidget will remain in its default "hidden" state unless/until you explicitly call `show()` on the new child QWidget.  OTOH if you add the child QWidget into a hierarchy that hasn't had `show()` called on it yet, then when the `show()` method is eventually called, it will effect the newly-added QWidget (along with everything else in that subtree).